# Formatting a *relative* amount of time (ms) in Java?

Tags: java

I want to log certain events by their relative timing.  I don't care at what hour of the day something happened, I just want to know that an event happened 2 minutes, 13 seconds and 243 milliseconds ago.  Let's say I have:

```
long event_ms = [some time in ms since the Epoch];
long now_ms = [current time in ms since the Epoch];
long diff_ms = now_ms - event_ms;
```

diff_ms contains the number of milliseconds AGO that the event occurred.  I just want to format this time (using the format HH:mm:ss.SSS).  What's the easiest way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code works fine for me:

```
    int diff_ms = 61200;
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String str = fmt.format(new Date(diff_ms));
    System.out.println(str);
```

It prints `00:01:01.200`

Pay attention on setting the timezone. Otherwise the result depends on your default timezone and will be wrong everywhere except GMT.

Comment: Since Date is deprecated, what would be the appropriate replacement?  Thanks!

Comment: Date is not depricated. Only its setters and getters. And I did not use them. So example I posted is clear from usage of depricated API.

Comment: One should not use Date to represent something that is not an instant in time. This is not a good solution

Comment: The only place where Date is used here is in call to `format()` method that works with this type only.

Answer (score 8):

The class [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) contains methods to convert millis in to hours, minutes and seconds:

```
String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
);
```

P.S Note that TimeUnit is available only in 1.5+

Comment: Arghh! I never knew about TimeUnit and wrote my own method to do this. Not that it's hard, but it was a waste of time...

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach

```
String.format("%d min, %d sec, %d ms", 
              millis/60/1000, millis/1000%60, millis%1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need TimeUnit to do simple integer operations such as division and module, nor you need to use TimeZone(s), since you are dealing with a delta, which is time-zone independent. Here's the solution I would have used:

```
long millis = 123456L;
String delta = String.format(
  "%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d",
  (millis / (1000L * 60L * 60L)),
  (millis / (1000L * 60L)) % 60,
  (millis / 1000L) % 60,
  millis % 1000L
);
```